# Can't boot Windows or see Windows partitions after Ubuntu installation

Tags: data-recovery

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 13 (32 bit) using the *Install alongside Windows 8* option.  However it wouldn't reboot.

Then I downloaded Ubuntu 64 bit installed it choosing something like *Replace old Ubuntu 13 installation*.

Now I can boot only Ubuntu and it won't let me choose Windows 8. I suspect somehow the Windows partition has gone? Before installing Ubuntu I had 3 partitions:

- C: with WIN8
- D: with System Recovery
- E: Create to store file videos photos etc...

Now it looks like everything has merged into 1 Linux partition.

Would it be possible to restore at least the win E volume where I had EVERYTHING?

Please help I'm desperate... years of pictures :(

[Here're my logs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7173458/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've override your old partitions with the partitions for ubuntu and swap.
That's why it's strongly recommended to do a backup before to install a new operating system or to do critical changes in your computer.

Now, try your luck with this link: [Data Recovery in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)

Answer (score 0):

As Akronix has said, you've wiped your Windows installation. If you need to recover personal data files, your only hope at this point is a tool like [PhotoRec,](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which scans a disk for signs of files and extracts them to another disk. If this is your need, ***stop using the disk immediately!!!*** Every second you use the computer as it is now, the odds of it overwriting an old file goes up. Boot using an emergency disk (on CD-R or USB flash drive) and do your recovery from there. Note that there are Windows tools that are similar to PhotoRec and that may do a better job than PhotoRec for recovering files from NTFS, but I don't happen to know what they are, so I can't point you to them. Asking on a Windows forum may be helpful. If you have lots of money and your data are particularly valuable, there are professional data-recovery services available. I don't happen to have any specific recommendations, though.

If you don't need to recover personal data files, your best bet is to shrink your Linux partition and re-install Windows. If the computer came with Windows pre-installed, you may need to pay the manufacturer or Microsoft for recovery discs, although [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft) offers some suggestions about legal downloads of Windows 8, so you could check those options first.

Moving forward, let this be a lesson on the importance of keeping backups.

Comment: [How to get the original filenames?](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_FAQ) If the filesystem isn't damaged, try TestDisk. TestDisk may be able to undelete the file with its filename. It works for FAT, NTFS and ext2.In some case, the filename is stored in the file itself, PhotoRec try to recover the filename in this case but most of the time, PhotoRec can't. PhotoRec uses the logical sector number to create the filename, it appends the original filename or the document title when possible, the filename ends by the file extension.